# String concatenation from vector tuple

Tags: rust

This is as simple as it gets, yet I have no clue why it doesn't work.

```
fn main() {
    let vector = vec![("foo".to_string(), "bar".to_string())];
    let string = vector[0].0 + vector[0].1;
}
```

Error

```
src/main.rs:3:29: 3:40 error: mismatched types:
 expected `&str`,
    found `collections::string::String`
(expected &-ptr,
    found struct `collections::string::String`) [E0308]
src/main.rs:3   let string = vector[0].0 + vector[0].1;
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

So then I change it to this:

```
fn main() {
    let vector = vec![("foo".to_string(), "bar".to_string())];
    let string = &*vector[0].0 + &*vector[0].1;
}
```

Get another error

```
src/main.rs:3:15: 3:28 error: binary operation `+` cannot be applied to type `&str` [E0369]
src/main.rs:3   let string = &*vector[0].0 + &*vector[0].1;
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/main.rs:3:15: 3:28 help: run `rustc --explain E0369` to see a detailed explanation
src/main.rs:3:15: 3:28 note: an implementation of `std::ops::Add` might be missing for `&str`
src/main.rs:3   let string = &*vector[0].0 + &*vector[0].1;
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I've exhausted all the combinations I could think of. What am I missing here?

Comment: `vector[0].0 + &vector[0].1`, but it will move out of `vector[0].0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does not work because concatenation is defined only on `String`, and it consumes its left operand:

```
let s = "hello ".to_string();
let c = s + "world";
println!("{}", c);  // hello world
println!("{}", s);  // compilation error
```

Therefore it needs by-value access to the string, but it cannot be done with indexing on a vector - they can only return references into the vector, not values.

There are several ways to overcome this, for example, you can clone the string:

```
let string = vector[0].0.clone() + &vector[0].1;
```

Or you can use formatting:

```
let string = format!("{}{}", vector[0].0, vector[0].1);
```

Or you can take the value out of the vector with [`remove()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/collections/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.remove) or [`swap_remove()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/collections/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.swap_remove):

```
let string = match vector.swap_remove(0) {
    (left, right) => left + right
};
```

The latter, naturally, is appropriate if it's okay for you to lose the state of the vector. If you want to do this for the whole vector, it is better to iterate it by value, consuming it in the process:

```
for (left, right) in vector {
    let string = left + right;
}
```